# Angular 2 + how to select and loop over multiple elements with the same selector (elementRef.nativeElement)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

In my component I am trying to unselect all checkboxes with the same class name.

`querySelector` selects only the first one each time (or once)... and `querySelectorAll` does not select anything.

this is the function. I know its wrong to use jQuery like that but it illustrates my goal.

```
unsetAllOptions(){
    var self = this;
    var i = 0;
    $("input.option_input").each(function(){
        i++;
        var element = self.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector("input.option_input")[i];
        if(element.checked){
            // console.log(i)
            console.log('unchecking:',i);
            element.checked=false;
            element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            element = "";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608352/1713468

Comment: i see that works but i cant understand all the `unit` mentions. Im hoping to find some kind of query selector and not do formBuilder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**Option 1:**

As you are using .each method, using index and value you can avoid querySelectorAll, reference - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$("input.option_input").each(function(index,element){
        if(element.checked){
            element.checked=false;
            element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            element = "";
        }
    });
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aGoMKz?editors=1010

**Option 2**

Option2 and preferred way is to avoid document.querySelectorAll ,as it fetches all matching elements of the DOM irrespective of the current component

Steps to achieved expected result,

1. Use Renderer and ElementRef to fetch current component elements
2. Use this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll for fetching matching elements

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elem: ElementRef){}

  unsetAllOptions(){
    const elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.option_input');
    elements.forEach(element => {
     if(element.checked){
        element.checked = false
     }
});
 }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<input type="checkbox" class="option_input" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="option_input" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="option_input" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="option_input" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="option_input">

<button (click)="unsetAllOptions()">UncheckAll</button>
```

code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aei58i?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Will try all of these and share how it goes tomorrow

Comment: @Omar any luck?

Comment: why you imported Renderer?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me but if you know a better way. Let me know

```
unsetAllOptions(){
    var self = this;
    var i = -1;
    $("input.option_input").each(function(){
        i++;
        var element = self.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("input.option_input")[i];
        element.checked=false;
    });
}
```