# Get list of all available <button> elements in component html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Say my component is simple, like:

```
<div>
  <button id="one" #one>one</button>
  <button id="two" #two>two</button>
  <button id="three" #three>three</button>
</div>
```

Would it be possible to return a list of all of the buttons?

ie.

```
constructor() {
  let buttonList = findByElement('button');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()`

```js
var div=document.getElementById("div");
var a=div.querySelectorAll('button');
console.log(Object.values(a))
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="one" #one>one</button>
  <button id="two" #two>two</button>
  <button id="three" #three>three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely this would find everything in the whole document, not just within that component?

Comment: I think I solved it with `document.getElementsByTagName('button');`

Answer (score 0):

If you add `Renderer` and `ElementRef` to your component, you should then be able to access the element in question:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elem: ElementRef){}
```

I believe from within your component you can call:

```
const elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Which would give you the elements you need. It's important when using this method to ensure that you're running your code at some point after the component is initialised, not in the constructor as was the case with your original code, as we need to ensure we have access to the DOM for this component. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886571/angular-2-how-to-select-and-loop-over-multiple-elements-with-the-same-selector) has more detail.

Comment: What would `elem` be defined as?

Comment: and you have to call this in ngAfterViewInit, not in constructor as OP did.

Comment: @physicsboy `elem` refers to `private elem: ElementRef` which is in the constructor