# How to get document object in angular component

Tags: angular

can anybody tell how to get document object angular. I have tried with ElementRef. It is not working

```
let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.classImLookingFor');
```

Can anybody suggest how to get querySelectorAll in component in angular?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886571/angular-2-how-to-select-and-loop-over-multiple-elements-with-the-same-selector,  
                https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll,    
One of this could help you

Comment: You need to have this line in ngAfterViewInit, not on ngOnInit..... Also you make sure, there are no *ngIf on the selector elements

Answer (score 4):

1. import Inject from @angular/core and DOCUMENT from @angular/common

```
import { Component, Inject, ... } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

2. Inject the DOCUMENT interface inside your class' constructor like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

    // ...

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

3. Now you can use the document object inside your class methods. Intellisense will display all the methods and properties of the Document interface, such as querySelector, getElementById, addEventListener etc..

```
myMethod() {
   this.document.<whatever ...>

   // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: it is not working in angular 8

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer needs a small update, since the latest way of doing this in Angular 16, following the [standalone standard](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) that Angular is heading to, is:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  ...
})
class MyComponent {
  private document = inject(DOCUMENT);

  ngOnInit() {
     this.document.<whatever ...>
  }
}
```